# Checking whether there are real solutions to the polynomial equation $x^4-4x^3+ax^2+bx+1=0$ for certain $a, b$

Tags: polynomials, roots

> $x^4-4x^3+ax^2+bx+1=0$ What should $a$ and $b$ be, so that the given equation has four real roots?
>
> 1. $(4, -6)$
> 2. $(6, -4)$

Not getting any start. Tried Descartes sign rule conditions to real roots but couldn't  figure out the exact answer.

Comment: Do you mean ONLY real roots ? or at least one real root?

Answer (score 2):

When $(a, b) = (4, -6)$, evaluating the l.h.s. at $x = 1$ gives $-4$, but the leading coefficient is positive, so there are at least two distinct, real solutions. (In fact, we can show that the derivative of the l.h.s. has a single root, so there are precisely two real solutions.)

When $(a, b) = (6, -4)$, the l.h.s. factors as $(x - 1)^4$, so the equation has a (unique) solution at $x = 1$.

Comment: so whats the answer for it

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Clarify the question!

Comment: all 4 an edit has been made @jean

Comment: @ArchisWelankar This answer as written still addresses the edited version of the equation, no?

Comment: but still confused between two options  are both correct??

Comment: I'm not sure what the confusion is, exactly: The answer says that there are *precisely* two real solutions for $(a, b) = (4, -6)$, and one can show this using the method I mentioned (showing that the derivative of the l.h.s. only has a single root).